# ...(,) несмотря на тО, что

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, логическое-ударение, отглагольный-предлог

`Многие продолжали работать(,) несмотря на тó, что было уже поздно.`

`Мы(,) несмотря на тó, что лил дождь, продолжали прогулку.`

`Они продолжили путь(,) несмотря на тó, что были очень уставшими.`

Ударение стоит на первую часть союза везде, и вхождений в состав сказуемого нет!

Мне лишь интересно узнать: если ставим ударение на первую часть союза НЕСМОТРЯ НА ТО ЧТО, расчленяя его, сохраняется ли запятая *перед* союзом ввиду участия отглагольного предлога НЕСМОТРЯ НА?

Comment: (1) Придаточное в середине предложения вроде бы по всем правилам не расчленяется.  (2) Ударение можно изучать по предложениям, оформленным по грамматике, а не по Грамоте.  А Грамота интонационный анализ не рассматривает.  (3) Расчленение союза задает ударную позицию для местоименной части союза.